# Combine several post request into one, transform this batch and return answers for these post requests

Tags: python, flask, request, aiohttp

I'm not good at work with request, but my current project require this. Now my server works like this:

```
from aiohttp import web

@routes.post('/')
async def my_func(request):
    post = await request.json()
    answer = '... do something on GPU ...'
    return web.json_response(answer)`
```

But I want combine several requests into one and do my function on GPU only once. And after that return responses for all requests (may be in the loop). I can change aoihttp to different package if it necessary for solving.

For example, post request contains fields: {'id':1, 'data':'some data 1'}.

(1) I want wait 5 requests, combine data to list ['some data 1', ..,'some data 5']

(2) and then apply my function to this list (it returns me list of answers ['answer 1', ..,'answer 5']

(3) And after that I want make response for each request like this {'id':1, 'answers':'answer_1'}

I don't now how to realize steps (1) and (3).

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Are you saying - different people will submit post requests and you want to process them all together? Or do you mean the same person will submit post request multiple times and you want to process them all together?

Comment: I tried to expand the question. Yes, different people will submit post requests and I want to process them all together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep a **cache** of `requests` (questions) and `responses` (answers) and a `background task` that checks said cache; when the questions cache length reaches 5 you run the **GPU function** and populate the answers cache.
Each request waits until the answers cache has the data it needs.

### server.py

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web


def gpu_func(items):
    """Send a batch of 5 questions to GPU and return the answers"""
    answers = {}
    for item in items:
        answers[item["id"]] = "answer for data: " + item["data"]
    return answers


async def gpu_loop(app):
    """Check questions cache continuously and when we have 5 questions process them and populate answers cache"""
    while True:
        if len(app.cache["questions"]) >= 5:
            print("running GPU function")
            answers = gpu_func(app.cache["questions"][:5])
            print("got %d answers from GPU" % len(answers))
            app.cache["answers"].update(answers)
            app.cache["questions"] = app.cache["questions"][5:]
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)  # sleep for 50ms


async def handle(request):
    """Main request handler: populate questions cache and wait for the answer to be available in the answers cache"""
    data = await request.post()
    print("got request with data ", data)
    request.app.cache["questions"].append(data)
    # can implement here a time limit using a counter (sleep_delay*counter = max time for request)
    while True:
        if data["id"] in request.app.cache["answers"]:
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(0.05)
    answer = request.app.cache["answers"].pop(data["id"], "unknown")
    return web.Response(text=answer)


# create background task (gpu_loop)
async def start_background_tasks(app):
    app.gpu_loop = asyncio.create_task(gpu_loop(app))


# stop background task on shutdown
async def cleanup_background_tasks(app):
    app.gpu_loop.cancel()
    await app.gpu_loop


def main():
    app = web.Application()
    app.cache = {"questions": [], "answers": {}}
    app.add_routes([web.post("/", handle)])
    app.on_startup.append(start_background_tasks)
    app.on_cleanup.append(cleanup_background_tasks)
    web.run_app(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

### client.py

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def make_request(session, num):
    """Make a single request using the existing session object and custom number"""
    url = "http://127.0.01:8080"
    data = {"id": num, "data": "question %d" % num}
    response = await session.post(url, data=data)
    text = await response.text()
    return text


async def main():
    """Make 20 consecutive requests with a delay of 20 ms between them"""
    tasks = []
    session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
    for i in range(20):
        print("making request %d", i)
        task = asyncio.ensure_future(make_request(session, i))
        tasks.append(task)
        await asyncio.sleep(0.02)
    responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    for response in responses:
        print(response)
    await session.close()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Depending on **concurrency** (how often the requests are being made from the client side) and **processing time** (how long it takes to process a group of requests) you might need to tweak the **timing** (sleep) and cache **limit** (how many requests to keep in the cache).

Hope this gets you started.